# Telerik RadGrid bound to web service without Linq

Tags: web-services, data-binding, telerik, radgrid, dataview

I want to bind a Telerik RadGrid to a web service without using Linq. In all examples I can find, the web service has to return a List(Of MyObject); I've tried this, and it works great. However, the table I'm binding to may at runtime have additional columns, or columns may have different data type, so I can't use a static MyObject class to represent the table at compile time. I also don't know at compile time which columns need to be displayed in the grid. I would like to bind to a web service for performance reasons.

I've tried having the web service method return a DataView, and cast it a lot of different ways, but it's not working. How would I write the GetData / GetDataAndCount method of the web service to return the data from a DataView or other non-linq data source?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize DataTable similar to [my blog post](http://blogs.telerik.com/vladimirenchev/posts/10-01-22/how_to_serialize_your_datatable_to_silverlight_using_wcf_service.aspx). Here is an example:

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" AllowPaging="true" runat="server">
        <MasterTableView>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="ID" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="Name" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Contact" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
        <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="true" />
        <ClientSettings>
            <DataBinding Location="WebService.asmx" SelectMethod="GetDataAndCount" />
        </ClientSettings>
    </telerik:RadGrid>

    <%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="WebService" %>

using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Services;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public Telerik.Web.UI.GridBindingData GetDataAndCount(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows)
    {
        var table = GetDataTable("select * from customers");

        var columns = table.Columns.Cast<System.Data.DataColumn>();

        var data = table.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(r => columns.Select(c => new { Column = c.ColumnName, Value = r[c] })
            .ToDictionary(i => i.Column, i => i.Value != System.DBNull.Value ? i.Value : null))
            .Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows)
            .ToList<object>();

        return new Telerik.Web.UI.GridBindingData() { Data = data, Count = table.Rows.Count };
    }

    public System.Data.DataTable GetDataTable(string query)
    {
        var connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connString);
        var adapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, conn);

        var table = new System.Data.DataTable();

        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            adapter.Fill(table);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return table;
    }
}
```